# methods and actions inside class definition

Tags: android, arrays, class, methods

With the caveat I am fairly new to android programing
I was having some trouble with an string array declaration along these lines

```
String[] title = {
"Abundance",
"Anxiety",
"Breakups",
"Bruxism"};

String[] name = {
"test1",
"test2",
"test3",
"test4"};
```

The problem arose when I made this change

```
String[] title = {
"Abundance",
"Anxiety",
"Breakups",
"Bruxism"};

String urlbase = "http://www.somewhere.com/data/";
String imgSel = "/logo.png";
String[] mStrings = new String[title.length];

for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++) {
    mStrings[i] = urlbase + title[i].toLowerCase() + imgSel;
    System.out.println(mStrings[i]);
}
```

and then on the System.out line I saw this error

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

which confused me and other for a long time until I found something I had no method, all of the previous statements were made in the class declaration.

***learned something here

I saw this in another post and tried their solution which was to add this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


}
```

around my 'actions' and this looked like the right thing and made sense so I tried it.
When I did it eclipse blew a screw and no gives me something really weird
I can't even copy it but it shows up in the console window

```
<terminated> MainActivity (1) [Java Application] /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Version/1.4/Home/bin/java (Nov 3, 2012 9:47:42 PM)
```

The bad part is that even if I erase the code and Clean the project that same error keeps occurring so code was that was working and I try this change see it stop working and remove the code  sremains broken

The questions is two parts how do I fix this and what is the exact syntax I need to put in place so I can have my actions inside a method

Here is my original code which should work but it has no the for loop mentioned above is commented out this was actually working just not as I wanted it this my change but now it won't even run due to my last attempt at a fix

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};    

String[] title = {
        "Abundance",
        "Anxiety",
        "Breakups",
        "Bruxism",
        "Decisions",
        "Zen"

};

 //I put my fix for the method issue here and eclipse blew up
 //I also uncommented the appropriate lines and commented out the mStrings declaration and
 //assignment



  //   String[] mStrings= new String[title.length];

 //   String urlbase = "http://somewhere.com/data/";
 //   String imgSel = "/logo.png";
 //   for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
 //     mStrings[i] =  urlbase + title[9].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase() + imgSel;
 //   }

    //String[] mStrings = new String[title.length];

    private String[] mStrings={
        "http://somewhere.com/data/abundance/logo.png",
        "http://somewhere.com/data/anxiety/logo.png",
        "http://somewhere.com/data/breakups/logo.png",
        "http://somewhere.com/data/bruxism/logo.png",
        "http://somewhere.com/data/decisions/logo.png",
        "http://somewhere.com/data/zen/logo.png"
    };   
}
```

Comment: There are multiple problems with your post.  It's too long, it's rambling, it does not contain either specific questions nor specific descriptions of problems.  You also use a lot of incorrect terminology.  As far as I can see, your need is for some Java tutorials.  If the correct use of semicolons and braces is causing you problems, then basic Java usage, rather than Android programming, is your issue.  Vote to close.

Comment: Well Simon it was successfully answered regardless. It was not semi colons or brackets That was simply what was indicated. The issue was statements being placed by accident outside of any methods and simply existing in the class declaration something missed by several others here as well. but I do thank you for checking it out

Comment: The weird part was the fact that adding a certain line of code could break it in eclipse so much that even removing the line of code could fix the eclipse issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

The above belongs in basic Java programs, and is not suited to Android. It handles its own activities and other program entry points.

Almost all code needs to be *within a method*, particularly `if`, `while`, `for`, etc. statements. We can put this code within `onCreate`, as that will be executed first.

Here is the basic idea:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // List / Adapter variables here

    private String[] title = {
        "Abundance",
        "Anxiety",
        "Breakups",
        "Bruxism",
        "Decisions",
        "Zen"
    };

    private String[] mStrings = new String[title.length];

    // OnClickListener here

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // super.onCreate and setContentView

        // Here is your for loop, untouched!
        String urlbase = "http://somewhere.com/data/";
        String imgSel = "/logo.png";
        for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
            mStrings[i] =  urlbase + title[9].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase() + imgSel;
        }

        // More onCreate
    }

    // onDestroy method here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I spent the last three days related to this one thing at last I am able to make progress